# Python DataFrame to_CSV - remove emtpy elements

Tags: python, dataframe, export-to-csv

Have DF which holds CSV like data ,
i.e:

```
                       0                         1                 2              3       4
0                     id                      None              None           None    None
15                status                      None              None           None    None
3            promotion{}               description              None           None    None
4            promotion{}                        id              t10            None    None
```

I'd like to export it to CSV where i want to exclude the None so i get :

```
status                      
promotion{}.description 
promotion{}.id.t10
```

I did:

```
df.to_csv(file_path_out,sep='.',header = None ,index = False)
```

getting:

```
status..
promotion{}.description.
promotion{}.id.t10
```

I'd like to remove those extra delimiters

Comment: Anyone can help with it ?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried using the `pandas.DataFrame.to_csv`, with other options but unfortunatly I reached the same result as you.

It is not elegant, but this worked here:

```
df = df.fillna('')

file = open('file.csv', 'w')

temp_str = str()
for i in range(len(df)):
    for j in df.iloc[i]:
        if j == '':
            continue
        else:
            temp_str = temp_str + str(j) + str('.')
    temp_str = temp_str[:-1] + '\n'
    file.writelines(temp_str)
    temp_str = str()

file.close()
```

Maybe you can create some function using this code.

Comment: I ended up adding simple sed command right after closing the file(i have thousands of file to procces) ,
although its not building python function - it actually simple, short and fast 


cmd = "sed -i 's/[.:]*$//' {i}".format(i=file_path_out)

Comment: If you have this possibility it is an interesting solution. Glad you made it. However, I will leave the answer if someone else finds this same problem and would like to deal with it inside python.